# Setup access.ini file permession so it can be read by php script

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, server, credentials, ini

I'm really new to this so sorry if this isn't clear.

I'm trying to hide my database credentials using an `access.ini`  file.

I have a AWS instance, with my scripts located in `/bitnami/joomla/index` (in short I have an html page that display data using a php file that queries a postgresql db). I've tried creating a new directory `/bitnami/joomla/config` where I placed the `access.ini`  file. However, my php script can't read it due to permission issues (I guess).

The owner/group for the files in `/bitnami/joomla/index` are `bitnami bitnami`.

And the owner/group and permissions for the folder `/bitnami/joomla/config` and its file are :

`bitnami bitnami`

`drwx--x--x`

Is my setup completly wrong, or is the issue easy to solve ?

Comment: `I guess`...well that's not much help to us unfortunately. What does "can't" actually mean in practice? If it can't read the file when you ask it to, you'd expect to get an error message, which might give some clue about the problem. Can you provide a [mre] of the issue including relevant code and relevant error / debug info? See also [ask]

Comment: Typically, the user of httpd is `apache` or `www-data`, etc. ... **not** bitnami

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using an access.ini file, consider using environment variables to store sensitive credentials.

PHP can read environment variables easily.

Additional details can be found [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.putenv.php).